# How do I save and email my .java file? (beginner)

Tags: java, eclipse

Java beginner here. I am using eclipse and my professor wants us to email our file as a .java. I can't figure out how to export the file without turning it into a "JAR" file. When I click save as, eclipse only gives the option to save it to src folder. Please help!

Comment: The .java file certainly exists on your machine, so maybe try to find it from File Explorer (if you're on windows). Just do an advanced search for the file.

Comment: Just go to the `src` folder for your project and grab the file

Comment: Copy the file in the working directory. What you appear to be doing is exporting, which is a step further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the .java file of your project by locating the src folder of the project you are working on.

Assuming you are using the default workspace location it should be saved here:
Go to C/Users/[You]/eclipse-workspace/[project name]/src/

If you have changed your workspace location it will be saved in that location and you can get the .java files by opening the folder, choosing your project and going to the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Milen Patel already gave you a working answer but instead of just navigating through your PC with Windows Explorer you could instead rightclick on the Class in Eclipse you want the Java file of, go to the 3rd point from the top (Show in) and go to System Explorer. Eclipse will automaticaly open it. (For people who like shortcuts, do ALT + SHIFT + W)